# Should I always use Task.Delay instead of Thread.Sleep?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task-parallel-library, thread-sleep

I have recently seen several recommendations stating that `Thread.Sleep` should never be used in production code (most recently in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29352170/c-sharp-thread-sleep1000-takes-much-more-than-1000ms-on-some-pc/29352367#comment46891534_29352367)).  Many of these advocate for using `Task.Delay` instead.  Most of the explanations I've found use UI applications as examples, since the advantages to `Task.Delay` are obvious (not blocking the UI).

In my case, I am using `Thread.Sleep` inside of a wait loop that polls a WCF service for a particular condition, like this:

```
DateTime end = DateTime.UtcNow + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2);
while (DateTime.UtcNow < end)
{
    if (ExternalServiceIsReady() == true)
    {
        return true;
    }
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

In this case, the following potential advantages of `Task.Delay` seem not to apply:

- The sleep time is fairly large relative to the typical timer resolution of around 15 ms, so the increase in accuracy of `Task.Delay` seems trivial.
- The process is single-threaded (non-UI) and must block until the condition is true, so using `await` has no advantage here.
- The ability to cancel the delay is not required.

Is this a case where it is appropriate to use `Thread.Sleep`?  What would be the advantage (if any) of replacing my sleep line with `Task.Delay(1000).Wait()`?

Comment: What does `ExternalServiceIsReady` do ? Maybe Sleep/Delay can be completely avoided.

Comment: Is there an option C to use an event? It might be more appropriate than this polling approach.

Comment: Option D is the superior solution, a Timer.

Comment: @HansPassant Can you elaborate on why a Timer is a superior solution?

Comment: No loop, no thread, no sleep.

Comment: Aside - it would be better to use a `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` instead of checking `DateTime.UtcNow`.

Comment: @HansPassant That would make it better than `Thread.Sleep`, but still doesn't seem to provide any advantage over `Task.Delay`.  Wouldn't I still need a loop to keep calling the polling function?

Comment: Hard to see why you bring this up, you were already determined to not use it.

Comment: @HansPassant You've said that a Timer is a superior solution, and I can see how avoiding a sleeping thread is advantageous, but I don't understand why else the Timer is a superior solution?  Why would I use a Timer when either Thread.Sleep or Task.Delay are so much simpler?  I don't see how a Timer helps me get rid of the loop.

Comment: @MattJohnson I've heard that before too, but the only advantage I've heard for Stopwatch is better accuracy, which I really don't need.  Are there advantages to using Stopwatch when the times measured are on the order of seconds, not milliseconds?

Comment: @nintendojunkie - Consider that clock can be *modified* (by the user, by NTP, etc.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's never an advantage in replacing `Thread.Sleep(1000);` in `Task.Delay(1000).Wait();`. If you want to wait synchronously just use `Thread.Sleep`.

If you really only have a single thread and planning to keep it that way, then you can use `Thread.Sleep`. However, I would still use `Task.Delay` as it's preferable in most cases and so it's a good pattern. I would only block at very top when you can't use `async` anymore, and even then I would suggest using some kind of [`AsyncContext`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/AsyncContext).

You can also use a `System.Threading.Timer` directly<sup>*</sup> instead of `Task.Delay` however you should keep in mind that the timer executes every interval and doesn't wait for the actual operation to complete, so if `ExternalServiceIsReady` takes more than the interval you can have multiple calls to that service concurrently.

An even better solution would be to replace the polling of the external service with an asynchronous operation so the service can notify you when it's ready instead of you asking it every second (that isn't always possible as it depends on the service):

```
await ExternalServiceIsReadyAsync();
```

---

<sup>*</sup> `Task.Delay` uses a `System.Threading.Timer` internally which also has a resolution of ~15ms.

Comment: And a more better way would be if `ExternalServiceIsReady` can throw an event that way there would be no need for sleep/wait.

Comment: @EZI That's asynchronous.

Comment: And what? doesn't it loop and sleep? What does asynchronous call change here? You only involve another task here.

Comment: @EZI An asynchronous operation means that it notifies you when it completes. It doesn't matter if it's done by competing a `Task`, invoking a callback, or raising an event. It's all the same and can be converted to other methods.

Comment: @ i3arnon I know what an async operation is, but it seems you don't understand its usage.  Replacing that line with `await ExternalServiceIsReadyAsync();` wouldn't change anything.

Comment: @EZI Replacing a synchronous blocking loop with an asynchronous awaitable call would mean one less thread (and its CPU cycles) wasted.

Comment: @i3arnon For your last comment: `Thread.Sleep` doesn't waste any cpu cycle. It keeps a usable resource(thread) hanging around, but no cpu cycles spent. Do you mean that while loop and those conditions?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel `Thread.Sleep` (as do `Task.Delay`) doesn't waste CPU cycles. It's the constant polling that does, and a single asynchronous operation (be it `async` or otherwise) solves that.

Comment: @i3arnon To be clear - In a constant polling still `Thread.Sleep` doesn't wastes cpu cycles; the code which does the polling does.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel of course. Just as `Task.Delay` doesn't. (though if we want to nitpick, `Thread.Sleep` would cause an unneeded context switch that *can* waste CPU cycles)

Comment: Another nitpick. `Task.Delay` creates a `Task`(memory allocation),  `task.Wait()` will spin for certain amount of time and `task.Wait()` will allocate a Kernel event after that point (kernel resource and user-> kernel transition) all of which is gonna take cpu cycles :)