# Task Thread Safe Calls

Tags: c#

I have been using system.threading for a while now and I trying to wrap my head around tasks.  How do you make thread safe calls to a UI control (for example a text box) from another thread using the TPL?

Here is a simple example where I want to update a text box everyone 1 second with the count of my secondary thread.

I have tried a few different methods but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await taskAsync();
    }

    private  Task taskAsync()
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => counter());
    }

    private void counter()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
            textBox1.Text = i.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Is this even possible?

Thank you

Comment: As a side note, you should use `Task.Run` instead of `StartNew` because [`StartNew` is dangerous](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html).

Answer (score 3):

Well in your current scenario I Think that a [Progress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193692(v=vs.110).aspx) would be most suitable.
I've made some alterations to your code below:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Progress<int> counterProgress;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        counterProgress = new Progress<int>();
        counterProgress.ProgressChanged += CounterProgressUpdated;
    }

    private void CounterProgressUpdated(object sender, int e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = e.ToString();
    }

    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await taskAsync(counterProgress);
    }

    private Task taskAsync(IProgress<int> progress)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => counter(progress));
    }

    private async Task counter(IProgress<int> progress)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            progress.Report(i);                
        }
    }
}
```

Since the progress captures the current synchronization context on construction then you should be good to go as long as you create it on the UI thread.

> Any handler provided to the constructor or event handlers registered with the ProgressChanged event are invoked through a SynchronizationContext instance captured when the instance is constructed. If there is no current SynchronizationContext at the time of construction, the callbacks will be invoked on the ThreadPool.

Comment: Thank you, I will dig deeper into the progress object.

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this?

```
private void counter() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        Thread.Sleep(1000); 
            // “There's never an advantage in replacing Thread.Sleep(1000); in Task.Delay(1000).Wait();”
            // http://stackoverflow.com/a/29357131/4267982

        Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { 
            textBox1.Text = i.ToString();
        });
    }
}
```

Or, as an option, another way without separate thread at all (so there's no need in synchronization):

```
private async Task taskAsync() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        textBox1.Text = i.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: The only reason I am using Task.Delay is because thread.sleep doesnt work in UWP applications.

Answer (score 1):

> How do you make thread safe calls to a UI control (for example a text box) from 
>   another thread using the TPL?

You generall do NOT.

If you need to update the UI, then you do that using Invoke. But from TPL directly - you do not want to update the UI too often because this always is a heavy redraw and unless you make a first person shooter frame rate does not matter THAT Much. 10 updates per second are PLENTY.

In this case you may want the tasks to update a central counter (using Interlocked classes) and once that goes above a certain threshhold in changes (or using a timer running in parallel) push that into the UI.